# How to use jsprit for calculating the shortest path

Tags: routes, graphhopper, jsprit

I have came across **Jsprit** which is the collection of the algorithms for calculating the shortest path but i have added the maven dependencies in IDE, is there any information for classes and methods that can be used for calculating the shortest path and where does network topology located calculation of the shortest path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsprit has no meaning of a network topology - you can use euclidean, real or manhatten distances or whatever. To calculate real distances or even time estimates you can use GraphHopper (as you've tagged you question with that) or other software for that purpose. Note: I'm the author of GraphHopper. Then feed the distance matrix you calculated into jsprit. See the documentation and examples of the projects on how to do this.